# Elasticsearch alias type to reference multi fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch alias fields to rename some fields in my mapping without needing to reindex everything. Works great. Now I want to rename some multi fields as well, like this:

```
"message":{
  "type":"text",
  "fields":{
    "raw":{
      "type":"keyword"
    }
  }
}
```

That's an analyzed field named `message` and a keyword version named `message.raw`. I can make an alias for `message` like this:

```
"title":{
  "type":"alias",
  "path":"message"
}
```

But I cannot seem to figure out how to alias the `message.raw` field. I tried different things.

1. Suspected that this would work out of the box by just using title.raw and hoping that Elasticsearch would convert it to message.raw. Didn't work.
2. Specified `raw` as a field in `title`:

```
"title":{
    "type":"alias",
    "path":"message",
    "fields":{
        "raw":{
            "type":"alias",
            "path":"message.raw"
        }
    }
}
```

This generates the following error when updating the mapping: Mapping definition for [title] has unsupported parameters: [fields : {raw={type=alias, path=message.raw}}]

3. Specified `title.raw` as a new field:

```
"title":{
    "type":"alias",
    "path":"message"
},
"title.raw":{
    "type":"alias",
    "path":"message.raw"
}
```

This results in an error: Cannot merge a field alias mapping [title] with a mapping that is not for a field alias.

Is this supported somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing multi-fields from an alias isn't supported. From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/alias.html#unsupported-apis): 
 `aliases cannot be used as the target of copy_to or in multi-fields`.

You can create an alias for your multi-field without the dot. What you need to do is simply to name the `title.raw` field differently, e.g. `title_raw`:

```
"title":{
    "type":"alias",
    "path":"message"
},
"title_raw":{                    <--- change the name here
    "type":"alias",
    "path":"message.raw"
}
```

Then you can query `message.raw` the same way as `title_raw`.

Comment: Not sure I get it. Would that allow me to search by the field `title.raw`?

Comment: You can search by `title_raw` the same way as you'd search by `message.raw`. `title_raw` aliases the sub-field `message.raw`. It's just a naming issue because of the dot in the name

Comment: That wouldn't solve the issue I guess. The task here is to alias the `message` field with all sub-fields. I can query `message.raw` today, why I want `title.raw` to alias that. I can see that I can just use `title_raw` but when querying through Kibana, everyone needs to know that exactly that field is named differently.

Comment: Well, field aliases are a "hack" anyway, sort of a temporary solution until a new reindex happens or old indices get deleted. The main reason alias fields have been introduced is to enable querying older time-series indices (with old field names) at the same time as newer indices, in the hope that older indices would one day disappear and only indices with the new schema subsist. You should not rely on that for the long term. Besides, the documentation mentions that `aliases cannot be used as the target of copy_to or in multi-fields`.